# Could we change css class on div id on click without javascript

Tags: css

```
<div id="test" class="active"> <div> <button id="someid"></button>
```

I would like to change class on div without jquery. Is it possible
result should be

```
<div id="test" class="not-active"> <div> <button id="someid"></button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript do to this?

Comment: i think either the request is without jquery or without js - different things

Comment: page will display on third party and javascript will not work.

Comment: @DenisTsoi withot js and jquery

Comment: You need to understand this -- CSS is for style. JavaScript is for manipulation. CSS cannot manipulate (*make changes to*) your markup. JavaScript can. CSS can only apply styles. JavaScript can define styles to your markup.

Comment: No can't do with css only

Comment: `clickEvent` is an event of DOM - javascript. If not using Javascript. That's can't do. I think.

Comment: Looks more like an XY problem here. What exactly is your problem? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Abhitalks - I have side bar menu open and close on click event and one class update active or not-active on click event
there is any way to change this thing using css or on click we can edit class or apply any class ?

Comment: @VipinSharma: In that case why can't you just override the classes in the CSS stylesheet with the style rules that you want.

Comment: you need something to listen to the onclick. however, if you wanted the `id="test"` to react to the button onclick, you could nest the div inside the button and use a input checkbox and simulate the on/off state

Comment: @Abhitalks that is correct how can we update #someid class when it's click?

Comment: @VipinSharma: Just define it again in the CSS, preferably at the last and add a comment that it is being overrideen jsut to avoid confusion to other coders. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/k7qxqfme/

Comment: @Abhitalks, thankyou but it's already define and we need to change it's property when clicked

Comment: You can't for the reason stated above.

Comment: @DenisTsoi thanks I override as per your suggestion added hidden checkbox .

Comment: @VipinSharma Nice! - I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no option to change class name in client side other than using javaScript or jquery. CSS is only for appending style so what you have asked is not possible.